# User Input to Call Forth A Function

Tags: javascript, html, button, event-listener

I'm sorry if this question induces a "sigh" as I am new to programming and am still learning a lot every day. My question is this:

I have a function I made that will calculate how much money you would make monthly based on what your hourly pay is. It's my first function and I'm sure it has a lot of gaps, but right now I'm asking how to add the proper event listener that will give the result of my function after a user inputs their hourly wage value and clicks the submit button. Here's my function in JS and the code for my HTML page that I'm using to test out my function.

```
function howMuchMoney(pay, hours, days, weeks) {

var pay
var hours = 8;
var days = 5;
var weeks = 4;

var monthlyPay = pay * hours * days * weeks;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = howMuchMoney();

return monthlyPay;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>

#myBtn {
border: 2px solid black;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
}


</style>

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="testscript.js"></script>
  </head>

      <body>
<button id="myBtn">Click Me!</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
      </body>



</html>
```

So I'm sure there's a lot wrong with my code but I'm open to feedback and suggestions. All I really want to know is how to make it so I have a place for the user to input their hourly wage on the HTML page, click the submit button and the return is the total they would make on a monthly basis. Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Look up text fields for user input, then look up how to use button.onclick

Comment: Gotcha. So I added an input field and tried to add that into my JS file. Here's what it looks like now. 

```function howMuchMoney(pay, hours, days, weeks) {

var pay = document.getElementById("hourlyWageInput");
var hours = 8;
var days = 5;
var weeks = 4;

var monthlyPay = pay * hours * days * weeks;


return "Your Monthly Pay is: " + monthlyPay;
}

console.log(howMuchMoney());
```
Although, the button still doesn't activate the function like I'd like it to and whatever is put into my input field, doesn't seem to be connected to my pay variable for the function to run.

Comment: Update your question with the new code